# I need an autocomplete component in Vue that also allows to add new data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In Vue I need an autocomplete component that allow to select multiple options, and i have examples in vuetify (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#examples). But i need some component that allows me to select data from autocomplete but also add new data that is not yet in autocomplete results.
I think the images will be a very good example to understand. Is there any vuetify or other alternative for this? Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [comboboxes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)

Comment: Thanks, found a perfect example there!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a codepen with an exemple of what u need: https://codepen.io/sinhada/pen/yLpYzJL

It uses the `no-data` Slot from autocomplete to add a method in the `@click` of a btn with the `search-input` property.

```html
<v-autocomplete v-model="values" :items="items" class="ma-6"
    :search-input.sync="search" outlined dense chips
    small-chips label="Outlined" multiple>
  <template v-slot:no-data>
    <v-btn @click="items.push(search);values.push(search);search=''">
    add: {{ search }}</v-btn>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    values: [],
    value: null,
    search:'foo'
  }),
})
```